# How to get an array with the following specifications?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a script to extract an array of words of my textarea which looks like this:

```
<textarea cols="150" rows="15" id="texto">
"RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX4.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X3|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGX6.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX8.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
</textarea>
```

I would like to obtain an array from this one, considering as separators the following symbols: "|", "~" and " " consequently my desired output would be an array with the following structure:

```
["RBD", "X", "RBD3", "C", "92173", "GJHGWO.NAYE", "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1",...,"SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"]
```

In order to achieve this, I tried:

```
var text = document.getElementById("texto").value;
console.log(text);
var splitWords = text.split(/[["\|~]/);
console.log(splitWords);
```

but I failed since I get:

```
["", "RBD", "X", "RBD3", "C", "92173", "GJHGWO.NAYE", " ", "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1", "↵", "RBD", "X", "RBD", "C", "92173", "GJHGX4.NAYE", " ", "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa", "↵", "RBD", "X3", "RBD3", "C", "92173", "GJHGX6.NAYE", " ", "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1", "↵", "RBD", "X", "RBD", "C", "92173", "GJHGX8.NAYE", " ", "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2", "↵", "RBD", "X", "RBD", "C", "92173", "GJHGXA.NAYE", " ", "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2", "↵", "RBD", "X3", "RBD", "C", "92173", "GJHGXC.NAYE", " ", "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa", "↵"]
```

which contains several symbols that I don't want such as: "↵", "" and
 " " I would like to appreciate any suggestion to fix it.

At the past I posted a question very similar but at that time I wanted to obtain a distinct array, that structure was:

```
splitWords = [RBD,X,RBD,C,92173,GJHGWO.NAYE,...,SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa]
```

Comment: So you're wanting a *single* array of all data from all lines, not an array per line, correct?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to construct a regular expression to split this text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575233/how-to-construct-a-regular-expression-to-split-this-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do your job well

```js
var ta = document.getElementById("texto");
   arr = texto.value.replace(/"/g,"").replace(/\n$/g,"").replace(/~/g,"|").replace(/\s+/g,"|").split("|");
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<textarea cols="150" rows="15" id="texto">
"RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX4.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X3|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGX6.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX8.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
</textarea>
```

Comment: This is almost what I wanted but there is a problem at the end of the array it finished with the following symbol: "", if you just fix it, this would be the best answer.

Comment: @neo33 that's what i was try to understand right now. You may temporarily add a `.pop()` at the very end of the line for the time being...

Comment: yes I agree, sorry that was so obvious but I was thinking If that would be a valid solution since if I change the text, I am not sure I am going to obtain more of these symbols, that is why I want to clean well the array.

Comment: @neo33 I guess now it seems all fine. Had to add `.replace(/\n$/g,"")` into the mix.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove newline chars.

```
var text = document.getElementById("texto").value;
console.log(text);
// Remove newline chars
text = text.replace(/\n/g, "");
var splitWords = text.split(/[["\|~]/);
console.log(splitWords);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I am still getting: "" as the first element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, what we are going to do is trim the final line break, perform a series of replaces to normalize the separation delimiter, and then split at that delimiter:

```js
var text = document.getElementById("texto").value;
var splitWords = text
  .trim('\n')
  .replace(/"/g, '')
  .replace(/\s|\n|~/g, '|')
  .split('|');

console.log(splitWords);
```

```html
<textarea cols="150" rows="15" id="texto">
"RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX4.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X3|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGX6.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX8.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
</textarea>
```

Comment: the only one problem with this implementation is that I am getting: " ", that symbols, sorry if i forgot to put it in the specification, but the " " symbols are part of my delimiters.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer but I would like to remove also that symbols, I appreciate your support.

Comment: Edited to remove the `" "`!